# Set Ubuntu to display only in the half of the screen

Tags: lubuntu

My firend has a PC which screen is broken. It is an old Notebook Sony VAIO (o not know the model). It is running Lubuntu 15.04.
The half of its screen is broken, but he hasn't got any money to fix it. So I want to set it display ONLY it the half screen. I have taken it to my house, with a Monitor, but he doesn't have a monitor, and he was to use it only by the half screen. To conclude:
i want to set the screen to display only in the half of it. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at `xrandr`.

Answer (score 0):

First some useful keyboard shortcuts to get an application to apper on one half of the screen. If the left half of the screen is broken you could press the super (windows ) key and right to snap the window to the right half of the screen. Or if the right half of the screen is broken press windows and left to break it. If the bottom half was broken then press super + up or if top was broken super +down.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard
Also if you have an old unused vga cable laying around you might want to check to see if there is a vga input on this persons tv as then you could use it as a monitor. This sounds too old but hdmi with an hdmi cable would work too.

Now with only half of the screen you may want to modify the panel settings so right click on the panel. Then hit panel settings. IF the bottom half was broken and you can't see the panel press control alt t to open a terminal and then supe plus up to get it entirely in the working half of the monitor. then you will need to run `lxpanelctl config &` to launch the configuration dialog and then press super plus up to make it in the visible top half of the screen. Since the bottom is broken you would likely want to move it to the top. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/lxpanelctl.1.html is the same as on vivid just there aren't 15.04 manpages on manpages.ubuntu.com yet for more info see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-manpage-repository/+bug/1448306.

If the right of left half of the monitor is broken you can right click on panel and panel settings and align to the working side of the monitor. as a panel on the broken part of the screen won't help you much. So right click panel settings and appernce under geometry select alignment on the left or right side of the screen that is working. and make it 50 percent. This may result in a rather crowded panel so

Also setting a margin in openbox configuration manager so that maximized windows do not cover the broken half of the screen. To do this you will need to know the resolution which can be found using xrandr in terminal. Then for the side of the screen that is broken in openbox configuration manager. 
The line that says current will be important.

Alternitively using your monitor to fix panel settings may be really helpful.

You can set a huge margin in openbox configuration manager so that windows will not take up the broken part of the screen. Set the margin to half the resolution along the broken side of the monitor. So if the left half of the monitor is broken set the margin equal to left half of the monitor. You can use galculator as a calculator to do the math on lubuntu.

Comment: Thank you! I will look at it. I will have this PC the next Saturday.